# Synonyms for "section"

Tags: synonyms

1. How I can replace the word "section" as the meaning of a part of a website? For example: "Friends section", "Event section", "Messages section" etc.
2. Can I name a small part of a webpage  "a block"?

For example: **This "block" of friends on my facebook page.**

http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_174kb.1390237697.png

Comment: What's wrong with section? Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: To get rid of tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Synonyms for *section* in this context could include *group*, *category*, *area*, *unit*, *division*, *part*, and *bit*. However, none of these would be particularly appropriate for distinguishing sections of a website, either because their connotations aren't quite right, or because they're rarely used in such a way, and therefore would draw attention to themselves--which is probably not what you want. If you really don't like the word "section," consider not using a word at all, and just referring to "Friends," "Events," "Messages," etc.
2. In that particular case I think you'd be more likely to see the Facebook widget itself be referred to as a *box*.